# Watch OS app Xamarin problem with installing app on watch from Watch app on Iphone

Tags: xamarin, apple-watch

I am working on create watchOS app using Xamarin, that connects on start to iOS app (in the same bundle). I am using apple watch simulator series 7 with watchOS 8.0 and iOS 15.0.

1. Build and deploy iOS app on Iphone simulator, then stop it.
2. Open "Watch" app on iOS and at "available apps" install WatchOS app this is a part of just install iOS app.
3. Loading animation is spinning around 2-3 minutes.
4. Alert is being displayed "This app could not be installed at this time.Could not install at this time."

On the real Iphone device and real Apple Watch Series 7, installing animation is spinning more than 20 minutes without any result. App was installed from Testflight (build for internal tests).

Anyway I can build and deploy Iphone app on simulator firstly , stop it and then build and deploy watchOS app on simulator. Both simulators are paired and can send messages using WatchConnectivity.

The main problem is than I can not install watchOS from Iphone. How to deal with it? Are there any logs?

Comment: Does your provisioning profile include the watch device? Please see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/deploy-test/device

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. You are right. After adding new device on apple developer website, then I was able to install the iOS app from TestFlight and then using Watch (iOS app), install my app on apple watch.

Comment: But this doesnt solve the Simulator problem does it? you dont need any registration for Simulator normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check provisioning profile to include the device so you can install it.
Here is a document you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/watchos/deploy-test/device

Comment: But you don't need a provisioning profile for Simulator, do you?